# How to prove that $H(S_1\cap S_2)\subset H(S_1) \cap H(S_2)$ and $H(S_1 \cup S_2) \supset H(S_1) \cup H(S_2)$

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

I'm studying convex analysis and my task is to prove the following inclusions:

> $S_1, S_2$ are non-empty sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $H(S) $ defined as the convex hull  of set $S$.
>
> Show that
>
> $H(S_1\cap S_2)\subset H(S_1) \cap H(S_2)$
>
> and
>
> $H(S_1 \cup S_2) \supset H(S_1) \cup H(S_2)$
>
> Can the inclusions be reversed? Explain why?

How should I proceed with a problem like this? I thought about using contradiction proof? What if I assume for example in the first task that there is a point $\textbf{x}_1 \in H(S_1\cap S_2)$, but $\textbf{x}_1\not\in H(S_1) \cap H(S_2)$ and show why this can not be? Is this the way to go? :)

Thank you for any help! =)

Comment: All you need to show is that the convex hull is inclusion-preserving, that is, if $S\subset T$, then $H(S)\subset H(T)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help @StefanHamcke =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to show is that the convex hull is inclusion-preserving, that is, if $S⊂T$, then $H(S)\subseteq H(T)$. The inclusions in your problem then follow easily.

In order to show that, in general, we don't have equality, consider $S_1=\{0,2\}$ and $S_2=\{1\}$, or $S_1=\{0\}$ and $S_2=\{1\}$.

Comment: @jjepsuomi: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got myself the first one so I'll add it here:

$$S_1 \cap S_2 \subset S_1$$

$$S_1 \cap S_2 \subset S_2$$

$$=>$$

$$H(S_1 \cap S_2) \subset H(S_1)$$
$$H(S_1 \cap S_2) \subset H(S_2)$$

$$=>$$

$$H(S_1 \cap S_2) \subset H(S_1) \cap H(S_2)$$

I think I can do the same with the second one:

$$H(S_1 \cup S_2) \supset H(S_1) \cup H(S_2)$$

$$<=> H(S_1) \cup H(S_2) \subset H(S_1 \cup S_2)$$
$$S_1 \subset S_1 \cup S_2$$
$$S_2 \subset S_1 \cup S_2$$
$$=>$$

$$H(S_1) \subset H(S_1 \cup S_2)$$
$$H(S_2) \subset H(S_1 \cup S_2)$$

so

$$H(S_1) \cup H(S_2) \subset H(S_1 \cup S_2)$$